# How to solve error in GWT Project

Tags: gwt

I created a web application project. It ran successfully, but shows one message.

i.e. GWT Module needs to BE (re)compiled message displayed. How to solve this error/warning?

Comment: By recompiling the module? :) Any more info? Which version of GWT, are you using Eclipse/Google Eclipse Plugin?

Comment: Hi,I include the 
 GWT file .i am also using Eclipse 3.5

Answer (score 0):

"GWT Module need to BE (re)compiled" - that means, you should call the app with the gwt.codesvr parameter, for example:

http://localhost:8080/MyProject/index.html?gwt.codesvr=172.16.0.43:9997

Answer (score 0):

This message must be coming If you are running GWT in Development mode? check if you have installed the GWT browser plugin properly, check if there are any errors shown in the development mode tab(in eclipse).